# Image Styles and Effects

Tags: media

Once I've created different Effects under Image styles. How do I flip between them in the Manage Display/Manage Fields windows for the content type?

I can't figure it out.

Or am I just meant to create Different Image styles for each different effect I might like to use?

Comment: what do you mean by flip?

Answer (score 1):

The display formatter for an image on "Manage Display" allows you to select which image style to use.

The image style itself contains the relevant effect(s)

Comment: Thank you. Drupal lets me create more than one effect per image style. What's the point of that? Can it use more than one? Or should I only have one effect per image style?

The slideshow looks different in FF and IE and I am wondering if it's because I've got more than one effect for the image style I am using...

Comment: _"What's the point of that? "_ so that you can run multiple effects on the same image, just like you've said :)

Comment: erm.. because you might want to do two or more things. Like convert the file type to jpg AND crop the image...